# Multiple domain server on nginx using proxy server need to force https

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a server with more than 4 multiple domains all running with proxy_pass the config files look something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # SSL certificate paths
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certificate.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

Once I save and reload the config file and go to any of the domains I get an infinite loop.

Comment: What's the response from `http://127.0.0.1:5000;`?  Could it be ignoring your `X-Forwarded-Proto` header?

Comment: Thansk! In the log files I don't see any evidence of this... Which log files can I post for this?